# Whoever removed the "@" in the directed comments...

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

Lately I've seen that whenever the comments are directed at me, I no longer see «@username blah blah», but just «blah, blah».

I don't think this is a good idea.

People will start to forget to put @, specially the new users(many may not even notice that is how we direct a comment to a user if they've never read a comment with the @).

Isn't there the possibility of turning back?

Comment: If you are the owner of the post, then `@Anold`is not needed, and is automatically removed. May be that is what you have seen?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   I'm referring to the case when I'm not the owner of the comment...

Comment: Here's an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619778/second-derivative-of-a-composite-function/1795473?noredirect=1#comment4180892_1795473

I cannot read my name in the comment of the other user, but it still showed up in my message box.

Answer (score 8):

There are some situations when a user is notified about comments even without being addressed using @username syntax.

Details on how [comment-replies](/questions/tagged/comment-replies) work can be found here:
[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

The situation you [linked to in your comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/whoever-removed-the-in-the-directed-comments#comment99767_25369) is mentioned there too:

> Note if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is [also notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts) if *@name* is not included.

You posted the first comment [under this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619778/second-derivative-of-a-composite-function/1795473#1795473) and the only other person who commented there was the post owner. Which is reason why you were notified, even without @username.

This situation is also described in this older post: [When is @ ping necessary to cause comment notification to take place?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/when-is-ping-necessary-to-cause-comment-notification-to-take-place)

Comment: Nice summary. I would just stress that the situation is like this since a long time.